# how to send file with variable to server with react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, file, react-hooks

I have a file and a boolean variable, how can I send this data from the client, here is my code, but it does not work

```
export async function uploadFile(file, isPublic) {
    if (file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('isPublic', isPublic);

const response = await fetch(`${FILE_URL}/upload`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${await GetToken()}`,
                'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;`
            }
        })
```

my server is ASP.NET CORE, but that's not the point, I think (I have [frombody] enabled there) and it also accepts 'file' and 'isPublic'

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can convert the boolean value to a string before appending it to the formData. Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
export async function uploadFile(file, isPublic) {
  if (file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('isPublic', String(isPublic)); // Convert boolean to string

    const response = await fetch(`${FILE_URL}/upload`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${await GetToken()}`,
      }
    });

  }
}
```

I hope I was able to solve your problem this way